# В input text при фокусе текст подчеркивается точечной красной линией

Tags: html, css

Как сделать подчеркивание?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подчеркивание применить можно, но вот подчеркивание точечной красной линией - не получится, т.к. такой стиль можно использовать в отношении html-элемента с помощью стиля: border-style: dotted, но не как к обычному тексту.

Comment: ну можно тогда для этого input сделать такой стиль, только подчеркивание будет на всю ширину поля ввода

Comment: Можно так:    #txt:focus {        border-bottom: 1px dotted #F00;    }    <input type="text" id="txt" value="Some Text Here ..." />Пример - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/gRTcp/1/